# TCP receive window and congestion window

Tags: tcp

I am trying to understand TCP's advertised receive window size and how CUBIC congestion control works.

1. Can we set the initially advertised receive window size ? I tried setting SO_RCVBUF, but didn't affect.
2. What can change the advertised receive window during transmission - what actions/events will affect the receive window size ?
3. What is the relation between congestion control and receive window size?

I am using Linux 3.11.

Answer (score 1):

> Can we set the initially advertised receive window size ? I tried setting SO_RCVBUF, but didn't affect.

It does. You must have done it wrong. You have to set it before connecting the socket, or, in the case of a server, on the listening socket, from which all accepted sockets will inherit it. Setting it after the connect doesn't work if window scaling is required, as that is only negotiated durimg the connect handshake.

> What can change the advertised receive window during transmission - what actions/events will affect the receive window size ?

Reading from the socket.

> What is the relation between congestion control and receive window size?

Nil.

Comment: my python code  `soc = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_STREAM )
soc.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.SO_RCVBUF, 55555)`  Can you give me some pointers to understand how receiver window changes.

Comment: @Kumaran That should work. What evidence do you have that it didn't?